# Use value of property expression inside expression tree

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

Consider a property expression like `t => t.MyProperty` where `t` is of type `MyClass`. How can I use this property expression inside a new expression where I perform a method call?

Pure `C#`:

```
class MyClass
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}

static void Foo(string foo)
{   
}

LambdaExpression GetExpression(Expression<Func<MyClass, object>> expr)
{
    return expr;
}

var myClass = new MyClass();
Foo(myClass.MyProperty);
```

Now with expressions...?

```
var expr = GetExpression(m => m.MyProperty);
var mi = typeof(Program).GetMethod(nameof(Program.Foo),
    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

var myClass = new MyClass();
// Now what??
// var call = Expression.Call(mi, ???expr??);
// var invoke = Expression.Invoke(call, fooParameter);
```

I want to use the result of `expr` and use that in the call to `Foo`. I know I can do this in two steps, where I call `expr.Compile().DynamicInvoke(myClass)` to get the value, but that is **not** what I'm asking for here.

I want to build an expression that takes a property getter expression and then performs a call to `Foo(`result of expression`)`. I cannot figure out how to use the expression as a parameter to the method call.

Comment: It's not clear at all what you are trying to achieve. Method `Foo` takes a `string`; your `Expression` produces an `object`. What expression would you like to use as a parameter to what method call?

Comment: if I understand it, you *should* just be able to use `Expression.Call(mi, Expression.Invoke( ... ))` ?

Comment: That's part of the challenge. Need for conversion, maybe. It is clear what I'm trying to achieve. For a given `MyClass` object M, I want to call Foo(M.MyProperty). The input is an expression as produced by `GetExpression` method above.

Comment: gotcha; give me a sec...

Comment: @l33t `Foo` takes a `string`, while `Expression` produces an `object`. Do you want a simple cast in between, because you *know* that the `object` is actually a `string`?

Comment: I will know. I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two ways of doing this, depending on the complexity. In this case, we can *re-use* the parameter from the inner expression - bubbling it outwards; we do this by discarding our old lambda, just using the `.Body` and `.Parameters`. For example:

```
var call = Expression.Lambda<Action<MyClass>>(
    Expression.Call(mi, expr.Body), expr.Parameters);

var myClass = new MyClass { MyProperty = "yay!" };
call.Compile().Invoke(myClass);
```

The other way is to use `Invoke` on the inner lambda:

```
var outerParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyClass));
var typed = Expression.Convert(Expression.Invoke(expr, outerParameter), typeof(string));
var call = Expression.Lambda<Action<MyClass>>(Expression.Call(mi, typed), outerParameter);
```

The second form (`Invoke`) is useful when you can't conveniently control the parameters in the two places - or where, for example, you have multiple inner expressions with *different* parameter instances.

Comment: Wow. Saved my day. Thanks!

Comment: Second approach is actually very useful in my case. Thanks.

Comment: @l33t there's actually a third option if you want: use a custom ExpressionVisitor to replace all of one expression with another expression - for example, to substitute an inner parameter with an outer parameter, but works for any expression. Can provide examples if you want.